# I want to delete data on backpress of activity in android

Tags: android, database, caching, delegates, back

on back press of activity delete data this code work but appication is crash

```
public void onBackPressed() { 

   File dir = context.getCacheDir();
   if(dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()){
   File[] children = dir.listFiles();
   if (children == null) {
  // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
   } else {
   File temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    temp = children[i];
   temp.delete();

          }

   }}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `appication is crase` please show log

Comment: can you show your logcat?

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions declared in manifest file?